# laravel use field in Eloquent model from another table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model named "User". I want "Password" field from Eloquent from another table, and when user calls the user::all() method, all selected fields from different tables come in the result.
How can i do that?

Results are not displayed in with() .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my problem solved by using  $appends  in Eloquent model  .

my code :

```
class User extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'user';
protected $attributes = ['password'];
protected $appends = ['password'];
public function getPasswordAttribute()
{
    return $this->getPAsswordMethod();  
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is extremely board and borderline unanswerable but I will give you a board solution.

You are able to establish relationships to other tables via the Model objects you create. Lets pretend you have a Password table which belongs to the User.

User model:

```
public function password()
{
return $this->hasOne(Password::class, 'FK', 'PK');
}
```

You can now do User::with('password')->get(['FieldName']); and this will give you all of the passwords which have the above relationship to a user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  , I have 2 database from two different connections , And do not want   to use  with()

Comment: @ehsan in which case you will need to query the other database and store the result as a variable and then pass it through in your query. If the tables are the same and share keys you can look at laravels collection methods